# One agent, several customers

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm using Google Dialogflow (former API.ai) with one agent, and I would like to be able to handle queries for many different customers with one agent.

The reason behind this is that I simply can't create one new GCD project / agent for each customer, due to the overhead and the quota limits on GCD projects.

I am looking for suggestions on tackling this. I am afraid that Dialogflow's algorithm will be cluttered and start confusing intents if I add too many of them that are closely related. I would like the agent to only go through the customer's list of intents and not the whole list of intents.

At the same time, I have common Small Talk intents that should be shared between clients. This means that setting the context as the client's ID may not be a fully viable solution, because the common pool of intents will not be used then.

To sum up, there are:

- Common intents, shared between all clients (small talk for instance)
- Client-specific intents (for instance, "What is [client-specific acronym]?")

How can I identify my user's (attached to one client) intent (ideally in a single request) given this set-up?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is probably sufficient for simple agents.

For more complicated agents, you might want to identify the client in the webhook for the first Intent (which you certainly have to do anyway) and then set a long-lived context for just that client. Then you can have other Intents which are tailored for the client and only get triggered if the context is present. To be clear, and quoting [the documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts#input_contexts):

> Input contexts limit intents to be matched only when certain contexts are set.

If you have components of the conversation that apply to all of them (small talk, common questions about using the service, etc) then you could make those versions not require a Context. If you have fulfillment for them, you'll still get any Contexts (and their parameters) that are active, so you can handle with client-specific information still.

Finally, however - you shouldn't worry too much about how many projects you have. If you get close to the limit, you can [request a higher quota](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7283050?hl=en).

Comment: So you are saying that if I use contexts, then only intents that match the provided context will be screened?

Comment: That is correct. I've updated the answer to be a little more clear on that point.

Comment: Thanks, I have an additional issue @Prisoner.
There are still common things between customers (small talk mainly). If I systematically send the client context to the API, then logically small talk will not work unless I configure it for every client. That's a hassle to say the least. Do you have any idea of a workaround?

Comment: It isn't clear to me if this is a continuation of this question or a new question, but I'd probably want to know how you're handling fulfillment for the small talk and if it is different for each one.

Comment: It's pretty related, I can create another one if you want...

Well there are shared intents between client, basically all of small talk. Then, I just get the action related to the intent from the API and map it to different messages for each client. What I want is to keep these "common intents" but still be able to contextualise other things by customer. Doing both at the same time seems unfeasible unfortunately?

Comment: I have edited my question to include this issue, if you wouldn't mind taking a look.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Basically - for shared Intents, don't require the context.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot know what the basic intent is before-hand. The bot is designed to have a core message workflow, which can be "broken" by submitting free text. This free text can be small talk or an actual question with an intent that is tied to client-specific responses. This implies I would need to make two API calls: one for client-specific responses and another after without the context in case of failure. Does that seem like the most appropriate approach to you?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I follow. Can you update your original question to include an example?